# How to add style dynamically using external css file?

Tags: javascript, css

How to add style dynamically using external style sheet? I tried using `createElement("LINK")`, but after `appendChild()`, the style will add to all check boxes. It shouldn't but affected to only one checkbox.

Comment: Share your code here?

Comment: That might be happening because your css might be targeting all the checkboxes. Chek you css rule selector.

Comment: Your question doesn't seems to match the stackoverflow quality. Reads this for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I got the answer thank u for the replay

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');

link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', 'YOUR_URL.css');

document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Where `YOUR_URL` is a url to your css file.